# C++ : Print value of unsigned short variable as unicode character

Tags: c++, c, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I want to be print a Bengali letter to the console, given that the `UTF-16` lower 2 bytes for that letter are stored in an `unsigned short` variable.

For example, for the letter `অ` (Reference : [অ](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=%E0%A6%85))

The unicode value is - 0985(hex)

And I have, `unsigned short unicodeChar = 0x0985;`

Now, how can I print this letter `অ` using the value of `unicodeChar`?

**Note:** I've tried this- `cout << "\u0985";` and it prints `অ` properly.

But I want to be able to print the character represented by the variable `unicodeChar`

Comment: Use wchar_t instead of unsigned short.

Comment: I read this short value from a binary file. I have tried doing this-
wchar_t wC = unicodeChar; cout << wC;
This prints the integer value of unicodeChar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use const char* to store the value.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const char* uC = "\u0985";
    cout << uC << endl;
}
```

If you want to use the value of unsigned short, you can use `setlocale` and print it by `%lc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main()
{
    if (!setlocale(LC_CTYPE, ""))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error:Please check LANG, LC_CTYPE, LC_ALL.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned short unicodeChar = 0x0985;
    printf ("%lc\n",unicodeChar);
}
```

Comment: `unicodeChar` is supposed to be a variable. Actually, I read this variable from a binary file. After that I have to print a character based on it's value.

Comment: How about use setlocale()?